# R loop that passes through list and vector and concatenates elements of each

Tags: r

I am trying to prepare equations for models. For this, I need to combine elements of a list (p variables) and vector (o variables) to obtain the following:

For model 1, o1=p1+p2+p3

For model 2, o2=p2+p3

I have tried unsuccessfully below:

```
outcome <- c("o1", "o2")
predictor <- list(c("p1", "p2", "p3"),
                  c("p2", "p3"))
link=c("binomial", "gaussian")

try <- function(outcomes, predictors) {
   for(o in 1:length(outcome)) {
       eq <- paste(outcome[o], "~")
       for(p in predictor) {
         for(e in 1:length(p[[o]])) {
           eq=paste0(eq, p[[o]][[e]], "+")
           #print(eq)
         }
       }
     eq <- substr(eq,1,nchar(eq)-1)
     eq <- paste0(link[o], "-", eq)
         print(eq)
         }
     }

 try(outcome,predictor)

[1] "binomial-o1 ~p1+p2"
[1] "gaussian-o2 ~p2+p3"
```

I'm trying to get:

```
[1] "binomial-o1 ~p1+p2+p3"
[1] "gaussian-o2 ~p2+p3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y, z) sprintf("%s-%s", z, 
   deparse(reformulate(x, response = y))), predictor, outcome, link)
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "binomial-o1 ~ p1 + p2 + p3"

#[[2]]
#[1] "gaussian-o2 ~ p2 + p3"
```

---

Or similar option in a `for` loop.

```
try_fn <- function(outcomes, predictors, links) {
   eq <- character(length(outcomes))
   for(i in seq_along(outcomes)){
       eq[i] <- sprintf("%s-%s", links[i], 
          deparse(reformulate(predictors[[i]], response = outcomes[i])))
      
      
     }
     
  return(eq)
  }

try_fn(outcome, predictor, link)
#[1] "binomial-o1 ~ p1 + p2 + p3" "gaussian-o2 ~ p2 + p3"
```

---

NOTE: Nested `for` loop is not needed as we are trying to create formula based on corresponding elements.  Therefore, just loop over the sequence of one of the elements i.e. 'outcome', use that as index to subset the other object corresponding elements, create the formula with `reformulate` and format it with `sprintf`

The `Map` is also doing the same where it creates the formula from each corresponding element of the input objects and format it with `sprintf` based on the 'link' elements

Answer (score 2):

Using purrr, you can do it this way:

```
library(purrr)
pmap(list(outcome, predictor,link), function(x,y,z) {
  
  paste0(z,"-",x, " ~", paste(y,collapse = "+"))
  
})
```